# Differences between *, self.* and @* when referencing associations/attributes in Ruby/Rails Models/Controllers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Assuming a Rails Model with persistent / non-persistent attributes, what is the best practice regarding referencing them? If you look at code publicly available, different patterns are used.

For instance, if you have an association from one model to another. What is the difference between using **self.association_name** and **@association_name?**. What is the preferable way?

Same as with non-persistent attributes defined with **attr_accessor :attr** in Models. You can reference them with both approaches, **self.attr** and **@attr**. What is the preferable way?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**`self.x`/`self.x=y` *are always* method calls.**

(`self.x` is just sugar for `self.__send__(:x)` and `self.x = y` is really just sugar for `self.__send__(:x=, y)`)

**`@x`, on the other hand, *only refers to* an [instance variable](http://www.rubyist.net/~slagell/ruby/instancevars.html).**

Using `@x` *will not work* with AR associations as AR only defines `x/x=` (*which are methods*) for its magical operation. (AR essentially just "captures" intent access through these methods and routes through *its own internal* data structures which are *unrelated* to any similar-named instance variables.)

[`attr_accessor`](http://www.rubyist.net/~slagell/ruby/accessors.html) allows "accessing both ways" *because and only because* it uses the same-named instance variable as it's backing (it has to store the value somewhere). Consider that `attr_accessor :x` is equivalent to:

```
def x; @x; end
def x= (y); @x = y; end
```

Happy coding.

Comment: Regarding associations: Do I actually have to use self.* to reference them? What is the downside of skipping self.* in this context?

Comment: @Scholle You must use `self.x = y` otherwise Ruby would think you wanted to assign the evaluation of `y` into the `x` local variable (which it will happily do, creating it if needed). However, assuming there is no variable `x` in scope, then `self.x` and `x` will both invoke the `x` method. Some people prefer to omit `self` in this case (I would). The big issue is *to be consistent*.

Answer (score 6):

Most of the time, you would prefer to use `attr` instead of `@attr`. It's because the method `attr` often set the attributes if it doesn't exists.

For example this model order:

```
model Order
  have_many :items

  def total
    @total ||= items.collect(&:price).sum
  end

  def taxes
    @taxes ||= total * 0.10
  end
end
```

This model works vell, if I had used `@total` instead of `total` in the method `taxes`, the calcul will failed if I didn't call method `total` on this object before.

As @pst point out, `@association_name` does not work for association, you HAVE TO use the method `association_name`.

Also `self.attr` should be used only to set an attribute (calling `self.attr=`) when reading the value you are better to use `attr`, see [this article : When to used self Rails model](http://www.themomorohoax.com/2009/05/21/when-to-use-self-in-ruby-rails-models)

Comment: In the article you posted it says "never use local variables that are the same name as attributes". This basically means you have to check your code each time after you have introduced a new attribute whether you have a local variable with the same name? For instance, you have two methods def start_time ... end (getter) and def start_time ... end (setter). According to the article, it is bad coding to use a local variable called start_time (e.g. to compute a time)?

Comment: The exact sens of this sentence is if you have an attribute, for example `@total`, you should not use a variable named `total` in a method of this class, this is because when you are using `total` as a variable it's confusing between using the variable `total` and call the accessor of `@total` (if existing). So you are right, you should not use a variable called `start_time` if you have a method `start_time` in your class but you may want to use the attributes `@start_time` to store the value **if needed**